# C# - ServerCertificateValidationCallback reporting NotSignatureValid

Tags: c#, ssl, x509

I have an application running in a few call centers. It's used by lots of agents all day long, but I'm occasionally getting an error report submitted about SSL errors. I use System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback to dump the whole chain and the error whenever there is a problem.

In this case, the error log shows the chain status and status information:

```
 Status: NotSignatureValid => The signature of the certificate cannot be verified.
```

I also export and dump the certificate info (thumbprint, issuer, etc) in the chain, including the PEM-formatted generated by this:

```
int certNumber = 0;
foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainElement element in chain.ChainElements)
{
    certNumber++;
    sb.AppendLine("Certificate #" + certNumber + ":");
    sb.AppendLine("  Subject: " + element.Certificate.Subject);
    sb.AppendLine("  Issuer: " + element.Certificate.Issuer);
    sb.AppendLine("  Serial #: " + element.Certificate.SerialNumber);
    sb.AppendLine("  Thumbprint: " + element.Certificate.Thumbprint);
    sb.AppendLine("  Valid Dates: " + element.Certificate.NotBefore.ToString() + " to " + element.Certificate.NotAfter.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine("  Signature Algorithm: " + element.Certificate.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName);
    sb.AppendLine("  Version: " + element.Certificate.Version);
    sb.AppendLine("  Encoded Certificate: " + Convert.ToBase64String(element.Certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert)));
}
```

I've triple-checked the results and verified that the chain is complete, and all the encoded certificates dumped (and double-validated via thumbprints, too) are all correct. I don't see any evidence of any MITM or SSL interception/inspection happening - they're just the correct, raw certificates, so I'm not sure how the certificate signature could be invalid.

Certificates are all 2048-bit, and the only odd thing I can see is that the subject cert and intermediate CA use sha256RSA for their signature algorithms, but the root CA uses sha1RSA, but that's been objectively confirmed on a separate network as accurate.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to say without a cert (and the issuer cert) to look at.  Possibly it's finding a wrong copy of the issuer certificate, and the issuer has changed keys since signing the original cert.

Comment: The serial numbers also match across the board. I'm unable to provide the cert itself, since it would disclose the identity of my client, which would violate various agreements. If you want me to check anything specifically, I can certainly do that, though.

Comment: When you get the error, the above snippet shows the same signature as when you do not get the error? Or another signature? You should also probably log data about the remote end at the TCP/IP level (IP address and port).

Comment: Could you define "occasionally" more precisely? It is related in any way from the source (happens in all call centers or only in some)? With time or day? etc.

Comment: Perhaps log chain.ChainElements[1].Certificate.RawData (as base64 or hex), to see if the successful and unsuccessful chains are getting different intermediates.  (or a higher index, depending on which ChainElement is reporting the error.  Heck, just log them all)

Comment: @bartonjs - Is the rawdata going to be different than what I'm already exporting (the base64-encoded / PEM version)?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - It is too rare to make any solid inferences about patterns in the call centers or times. I'd say that there's a few dozen reports across probably 30k-50k requests (ballpark guess). That said, I noticed a flaw in the reporting mechanism which might have suppressed some instances of reporting, so I'm fixing that and we'll see if the reports increase dramatically over the next few days.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - Yes, I get the same output if I log both successful and failure (although I have to log the successful version from a debug build running locally - deployments are scheduled, so it's difficult to collect new information from the field rapidly).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - Also, about logging the data about the remote end - is there an efficient way to do that from within the callback? Given the DNS-to-IP translation has already been performed at this point, I'm not sure if that data is readily available somewhere in memory, or if I need to go run the translation again.